# Change one column's value during a select - Sql

Tags: sql

I have following query:

```
Select * from Students
```

which retrieves: `Id`, `Name`, `Class`, and `School`.

I want, no matter what the value of Class is, to just get back Class = 10. Is there a way to do this in sql query?

Comment: your table structure would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

`select id, name, '10' as class, School
from students`

to get back a 10 in the class column regardless of what the actual stored class value is.

Answer (score 2):

Just substitute `10` if you want 10 for each row

```
 Select Id, Name, 10 as class, School from Students
```

If you mean conditionally

```
 Select * from Students WHERE Class = 10
```